# Checkout specific version of branch

Tags: svn

I thought I was pretty well acquainted with Subversion, but now something I thought would be trivial is stumping me.

First, I created a branch off of my trunk of a specific version, like so:

```
# svn copy http://server/project/trunk@13708 http://server/project/branches/b2012_03
Committed revision 13717
```

This seems happy.  Note that my trunk has had additional commits, thus the 13717 committed revision and my need to branch off of a specific version.  Anyway there it is.

Next, I want to checkout from the branch, but exactly at 13708 (where it was created) NOT 13717 ... this is important for my build process, don't ask it's not relavent to the problem.

First, I tried this (using the subdirectory 'conf' as a test):

```
# svn co http://server/project/branches/b2012_03/conf conf
yada yada ...
Checked out revision 13717.

# cd conf
# svn info
Path: .
Working Copy Root Path: C:\Users\Brett\conf
URL: http://server/project/branches/b2012_03/conf
Repository Root: http://server/project
Repository UUID: f3edbe5d-cdcd-4b35-8400-34e3054bdd74
Revision: 13717
...
```

That's not what I need, I need the revision at 13708... wipe out 'conf' and try this:

```
# svn -r 13708 co http://server/project/branches/b2012_03/conf conf
yada yada ...
Checked out revision 13708.
```

Hey, that looks encouraging, until ...

```
# cd conf
# svn info
Path: .
Working Copy Root Path: C:\Users\Brett\conf
URL: http://server/project/trunk/conf
Repository Root: http://server/project
Repository UUID: f3edbe5d-cdcd-4b35-8400-34e3054bdd74
Revision: 13708
```

The revision is right, but notice the URL.  It says 'trunk' instead of branch, in spite of checking out from the branch.

Two questions:

How is that possible?
How do I checkout a specific version from a branch?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your branch did not exist at `r13708`. Thus you've got nothing *there* to check out.

Whatever piece of your build system is dependent upon this behavior probably needs to be fixed.